# Magento2.2.x how to set admin Filter functionality on custom page on frontend grid?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, frontend, filter

I have created a custom page and I want to set admin filter functionality on a custom grid on the frontend.

Admin Filter - look the first image.
[image]

Frontend grid - want admin type filter above on grid

[image]

thanks